# Incorrect scaling when changing size

Tags: html, css, web

Currently creating a website and running into some sizing issues with an object and it's width/height in CSS. I have a table which contains a list of images that can be scrolled through and "shuffled", however this is only to a fix size and position. If I try to make them larger they separate for each other causing a mess of a homepage.

I have tired to use an element instead of an image and the problem still happens.

The current size of the objects are:

```
width: 390px;
height: 320px;
```

which looks something like this: [image]

as you can see, there is a space underneath this table which I would like to fill. So when I change the height to say "500px" this happens:

```
width: 390px;
height:500px;
```

[image]

changing the width instead does not fix it either, ei:

```
width: 500px;
height:320px;
```

[image]

[JSFiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/329umako/)

**So the  Problem**: Whenever I change the size of the CSS of the list it does not yield the proper results. I would like the table to fill the height of the page and preferably using percents so it can be adjustable to different resolutions. I have tried to both change the size with px and % and both did not yield grand results.  My HTML looks something like this:

```
<table align="right" border="0">
<tbody align="right">
<tr>
  <td><div class="rotate">
     <div class="accordian">
       <ul>
         <li> <a href="#"> <img src="images/square_1.png"/> </a> </li>
         <li> <a href="#"> <img src="images/square_4.png"/> </a> </li>
         <li> <a href="#"> <img src="images/square_3.png"/> </a> </li>
         <li> <a href="#"> <img src="images/square_2.png"/> </a> </li>
         <li> <a href="#"> <img src="images/square_4.png"/> </a> </li>
         <li> <a href="#"> <img src="images/square_3.png"/> </a> </li>
         <li> <a href="#"> <img src="images/square_2.png"/> </a> </li>
         <li> <a href="#"> <img src="images/square_1.png"/> </a> </li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </div></td>
```

The accordian/rotate class looks like:

```
 .rotate {
 -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
 -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
.accordian {
 width: 500px;
 height: 320px;
 overflow: scroll;
 /*styling for shawdows*/
 margin: 70px auto;
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}
```